# MS Visual Studio Community Edition not launching

Tags: visual-studio-2015

On unexpectedly showing some errors and debug messages I uninstalled and re-installed the Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community edition with update 3. However after several failure attempts, I installed it, but its not loading

[image]

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Have you checked [this Microsoft site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3039361), the installation log (at %userprofile%\appdata\local\temp) and the Windows Eventlog? Another promising page can be found [here](http://www.howtosolutions.net/2015/08/solving-installation-is-stuck-problem-in-visual-studio-community-edition/).

Comment: Try running VS in safe mode with "devenv /SafeMode"